# How can I extract the JWT roles in a reactive Service and use them in a Gateway route?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am having a spring cloud gateway app, which authenticate the bearer jwt against a oauth2ResourceServer.
In my route I would like to get access to the roles, which I extracted from the jwt.
How could I do that? Its my first reactive code.

My route is:

```
 @Bean
    open fun myRoutes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder, @Autowired webClient: WebClient, @Autowired grantedAuthoritiesExtractor: GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor) : RouteLocator? {
        return builder.routes()
                .route { p: PredicateSpec ->
                    p.path("/**")
                            .filters { f: GatewayFilterSpec -> f.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${generateBearerToken(webClient)}") }
                            .uri("MY_SERVICE_URL")
                }
                .build()
    }
```

My config is:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
open class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
    open fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
        return http.build()
    }

    fun grantedAuthoritiesExtractor(): Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {
        return ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
    }

}

class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor : JwtAuthenticationConverter() {

    override fun extractAuthorities(jwt: Jwt): MutableCollection<GrantedAuthority> {
        val claims = jwt.claims
        //      val marktId = claims["marktId"]
        val realmAccess = claims["realm_access"] as JSONObject
        val roles = realmAccess["roles"] as JSONArray
        return roles.map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it as String) }.toMutableList()
    }
}
```

Comment: when your service parses the jwt it builds a principal, and places it in the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` thats where you find the principal that contains who is authenticated and what roles are assigned.

Comment: How can I use it in my route?

I tried something like that:

ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).map(Authentication::getPrincipal).subscribe()

Comment: first of all you should never subscribe, if you subscribe you are blocking the thread until it deliveres the concrete value. The client subscribes, not your application. Second, you use it like you would with any mono. I have no idea "how you want to use it" thats not the question, you use it like you would with ny mono.

Comment: if you dont know how to use monos i suggest you read the reactor documentation in how to use monos. Its like asking "how does java work?" i cant explain the entire framework in a comment.

Comment: But shouldnt I wait, so I can collect all my roles from the ContextHolder?
Could you please correct my statement.

Comment: no in a reactive application you should NEVER "wait". Thats the ENTIRE concept of webflux. To be non blocking, never waiting. Thats why we use Monos and Fluxes, so that the system never waits, becuse if something isnt there, or ready, the server thread will do something else until the item is there so it can do its work. Monos and Fluxes arnt just something that makes you write cool code, it has a techical purpose. `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flatMap(item -> { // Here you do logic });` Then you return a new Mono/Flux to the next function.

Comment: i HIGHLY recommend you spend an hour or 2, and read the official documentation about what reactive programming is, the concept behind it and the "construction belt" analogy. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive